# How to get keystore password - android

Tags: android

I want to publish a new version of application, but I dont remember my passwords to keyStore.
I have my keyStore file and I try to retrieve password by java scripts for brute attack, but my password is too strong and had a lot of chars, that this is wrong way how to retrieve it..
I have my application in eclipse too.

Is some good way, how to easy get key Store password from old .apk file, or key store, or eclipse?

Thx a lot.

Comment: It can't be helped, you'll have to submit your app again with a new app with a new keystore.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't do Anything,

simple You have to `Resubmit` Your App , i.e new `APK` Signed with new `Keystore`.

**Backup all your `keystore` and `KeyStore-Passwords`

but their is way as suggested in this post, but i never tried.
please check it
https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

Comment: yes, but If I have resubmit, It will look as new application, but I want to look as same application with new version...

Comment: ya, it will be a New Application...you cannot give a app update/New App Version util you have Keystore and Keystore Password... so i think you have to sing a new APK with a new keystore and submit it to playstore. this time save the password also for App Updated/New Versions.

Answer (score 0):

No, if there were a simple way to bypass the keystore's password that would be a big security bug.

Also you can not retrieve the private key used to sign an apk, nor the keystore password from the apk itself as it does not include them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost your keystore or password, then there is no chance of getting it back. The best option is to resubmit the app.

Always store your keystore safely .Mail it to yourself thats the best way you can get back your keystore or its password.